# is date spinner available in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a app using flash cs 6. I need to implement date picker like in android devices. I googled a lot but didn't find any help. My question is, Is there any component like date spinner in flash cs6 ? Can someone give me a clue where to start ? I even tried to build my own with the help of few things I found but without success. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a component on Github. Maybe able to help you.

https://github.com/nidin/as3-date-picker

Comment: Thats not what I want. I need scrolling date like on android devices